# Read multiple messages from a same line using a separator in aix

Tags: aix

I have to read multiple messages written in a single line separated by a separator from a file in `AIX`.

Messages are separated like follows:

```
Message1#@#@#Message2#@#@#Message3#@#@#Message4
```

The separator is `#@#@#`. I want to read messages one by one and save them to seperate variables or an array.
I am using shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '#@#@#' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf("This is message %d: %s\n", i, $i) }' file
This is message 1: Message1
This is message 2: Message2
This is message 3: Message3
This is message 4: Message4
```

This sets the input field separator to `#@#@#` and then iterates over each such field for each line of input, printing out the fields individually.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is working but i need to read the messages one by one and perform activity on them one by one.

Comment: @HamasRizwan You have not provided any information about what you would need to do to the messages, so we are any solution would have to _guess_  in what form you need these messages in.  Here, I have assumed that you can do whatever manipulation you need in `awk` (which is the most natural tool for reading the messages one by one).

Comment: Sir i need to get one message at a time and then save all messages one by one in different variables. That is all i need to do.

Comment: @HamasRizwan "In different variables"? This is what the `awk` code does, strictly speaking.  Also, if you need the messages in separate shell variables, you should say so in the question, but be aware that using an array would be more natural (if you need to store them _all_ in a variable at all and not just iterate over them one by one). If you update your question, also mention what shell you are working with, and show any pre-existing code that you have tried writing to solve this.

Comment: I have edited the question sir.